# how to have a column only have specific values wihout filter(where and having) in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Expected output]

I have a column named String_Value which has a lot of garbage values and some important values.

If I filter out only important values like warning,critical. I will get only those job_ticket_ids which have string_value matching to the filter and that will also give me distinct job ids.

But what I need is the string_value column should only contain important values without any filter, for job ids without those important values can be returned as null. Also the job ids should be distinct.

I have attached my expected output for your reference. Please guide me through this if you have any idea.

```
select  distinct 
    Job_ticket_id,
    CASE WHEN (case when [Escalated to Resolved time] is null then (ISNULL([Escalated to Resolved time],0) + ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0)- ISNULL([hold time],0)) else (ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0) - ISNULL([hold time],0)) end) <0THEN 0 ELSE (case when [Escalated to Resolved time] is null then (ISNULL([Escalated to Resolved time],0) + ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0)- ISNULL([hold time],0)) else (ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0) - ISNULL([hold time],0)) end)  END AS JobTime,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(cat.[Time to Accept SLA],0) <0 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(cat.[Time to Accept SLA],0) END AS [Time to Accept SLA],
    cat.Report_Date,
    cat.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],
    cat.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)],
    cat.[Assigned Tech],
    cat.PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME, cat.Close_Date,
    cat.NAME, cat.[Ticket Status],
    isnull(max(cat.[Escalated to Closed time]), 0) as 'Escalated to Closed time',
    isnull(max(cat.[Escalated to Resolved time]), 0) as 'Escalated to Resolved time',
    isnull(max(cat.[hold time]), 0) as 'Hold Time',
    cat.String_value as 'String_value',
    cat.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
from 
    TEMP_TICKET_STATE_Category cat
group by 
    JOB_TICKET_ID, String_value, [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)], 
    JOB_TICKET_ID, [Problem_Type_Name(Child)], PROBLEM_TYPE_ID, 
    REPORT_DATE, CLOSE_DATE, PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME, LAST_UPDATED,
    TECH_GROUP_ID, NAME, ENTRY_DATE, 
    [Escalated to Closed time], [Escalated to Resolved time],
    [hold time], [Time to Accept SLA], [Assigned Tech], [Ticket Status]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirement. Do you want all the rows returned from your table, but with only certain values or NULL shown for the column you mention?  It would help if you explain what you're trying to do a little more completely.  And, you've tagged this question for both [mysql] and Microsoft [sql-server].  Which is it?

Comment: You mean like `String_value = CASE WHEN cat.String_value IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3') THEN cat.String_value END` (where val1, val2, val3, etc are your important values)? This would return null for any string_value that isn't val1, val2, val3, etc.

Comment: @O.Jones for example, job id 1048 has 5 values in the String_value column but does not contain warning or critical. Then it should return null value for string_value  for job id 1048. but if in case it contains warning or critical then those values should be returned.

Comment: @ZLK Yes you are right. But will i get distinct job ids if i do that?

Comment: Your job ticket id looks like it's unique (meaning it will always be distinct), so I don't see how it would affect that. The suggestion I made was to replace your current query's `cat.String_value as 'String_value'` with something like what I wrote.

Comment: Will you only ever see one warning/critical? Are these the only values you are looking for and will they be alone in the column? If so, then @ZLK provided the correct answer that will not generate duplicate rows. If the IDs were already distinct (which you included in your query so they should be) then they will remain so.

Comment: @ZLK I will try that out. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewO'Brien Yes one job id will only have warning or critical in string_value and not both.

Comment: @SankW you did not declare your question specifically..kindly elaborate to make it clear. Give a clear also your desired output.

Comment: Thanks @ZLK, it worked well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
select  distinct Job_ticket_id,
CASE WHEN (case when [Escalated to Resolved time] is null then (ISNULL([Escalated to Resolved time],0) + ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0)- ISNULL([hold time],0)) else (ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0) - ISNULL([hold time],0)) end) <0THEN 0 ELSE (case when [Escalated to Resolved time] is null then (ISNULL([Escalated to Resolved time],0) + ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0)- ISNULL([hold time],0)) else (ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0) - ISNULL([hold time],0)) end)  END AS JobTime 
,CASE  WHEN ISNULL(cat.[Time to Accept SLA],0) <0 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(cat.[Time to Accept SLA],0) END AS [Time to Accept SLA]
, cat.Report_Date
, cat.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]
, cat.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)]
, cat.[Assigned Tech]
, cat.PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME
,cat.Close_Date,cat.NAME
,cat.[Ticket Status]
,isnull(max(cat.[Escalated to Closed time]),0) as 'Escalated to Closed time'
,isnull(max(cat.[Escalated to Resolved time]),0) as 'Escalated to Resolved time'
,isnull(max(cat.[hold time]),0) as 'Hold Time'
,case when cat.String_value in ('warning' ,'critical') then cat.String_value else null end  as 'String_value'
,cat.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
from TEMP_TICKET_STATE_Category cat
 Group By JOB_TICKET_ID,String_value,[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],JOB_TICKET_ID,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)],PROBLEM_TYPE_ID, REPORT_DATE,CLOSE_DATE,PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME,LAST_UPDATED,TECH_GROUP_ID,NAME,ENTRY_DATE,[Escalated to Closed time],[Escalated to Resolved time],[hold time],[Time to Accept SLA],[Assigned Tech],[Ticket Status]
```